# How to see Spring bean dependency graph for annotation-base configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I know a way to see XML based configuration dependency graph (Spring Tool Suite) but that does not work for annotations such as `@Autowired` and application separated in maven modules. Is there any way  we can see that at project level or module level?

Comment: I guess intellij has a option. I have not yet tried it. Refer: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/08/quick-analyzis-of-spring-bean-dependencies/

Comment: thanks, I dont have intellij idea but I checked in Spring tool suite, where it shows beans in bean graph but not connection or dependency lines between them.

Answer (score 1):

The beans dependency graph feature in Spring IDE doesn't support non-XML-based Spring definitions.

There is a "live beans graph" feature that visualizes all the beans in a running Spring application. Maybe that helps in your case.

Comment: Thanks Martin but actually I was looking for dependency graph because  I want to detect circular dependency before running application. Not sure why like I mentioned above Spring Tool Suite is not showing connections between beans.

Comment: I would recommend to file an enhancement request for STS here: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS